# Not able to click img inside hyperlinked div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to show a dropdown when the `gear-img` div is clicked using jQuery but since it's wrapped inside an `a` tag, it ends up redirecting me to the url and I also want the whole div clickable. Please suggest a fix or a better way to achieve this.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="gear-img"><img src="images/ic-settings-black-24-px.svg"></div>
    <div class="dropdown"></div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: why u have given href="http://www.google.com" if you don't want to redirect it

Comment: Show your code, what have you tried so far.

Comment: Hi, I think for dropdown you can use select tag. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Comment: dont't use both href in `a` tag and `src` in `img` ,
you have to use any one . becouse `img` tag is inside `a` tag

Comment: If you want to make your whole div clickable so why are you not using some css and jquery? This is not a way to make the div clickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could stop propagating the event onto the parent a tag :

```
$(".gear-img").click( function(event){
     //you toggling code here....
     event.preventDefault();
     event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Add you clickable behaviour differently for every different-behaving div.

Comment: such an effective solution!

Answer (score 1):

An element that is `inline` elements should not contain `block` elements.

Change code like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.gear-img').click(function(){
    $('.dropdown').toggle();
  })
})
```

```css
.dropdown {
  display: none;
}

 img {
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top:10px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.google.com">redirect to google</a> 
<div class="content">
  <div class="gear-img"><img title="Show dropdown" src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg"></div>
<div class="dropdown">Dropdown</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because just adding an anchor (a link) doesnt make it work as you intend. It now does exactly what you told it to do; When you click it, it goes to Google.

You can drop the anchor add a little jQuery:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="gear-img"><img src="images/ic-settings-black-24-px.svg"></div>
    <div class="dropdown"> A<br/> B<br/> B<br/> </div>
</div>
```

and then you can use a little code to toggle the list:

```
$('.content').on('click', '.gear-img', function(){
    $(this).find('.dropdown').slideToggle();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.gear-img img').on('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation()
    $('.dropdown ul li').toggle('show');
    console.log('Image Clicked!');
  });
  
  $('a').on('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation()
     $('.gear-img img').click()
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.show{
  display:block;
}
.dropdown ul li{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.google.com">
Click Here!
  <div class="content">
    <div class="gear-img"><img src="https://indianflag.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/2.j"></div>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this.
Initially, keep your dropdown div display none. 
On click of that image div, we can show the dropdown div.Please find the code and let me know if you need further help.

```html
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
    </a>
    <div class="content">
       <div class="gear-img" onclick="fun()"><img src="images/ic-settings-black-24-px.svg">
       </div>
       <div id="dropdown" class="dropdown" style="display:none">
       </div>
    </div>
    <script>
 function fun()
 {
      var x=document.getElementById("dropdown");
      x.style.display="block";
 }
</script>
```

Comment: I have edited the code.Initially, there was no js code.